# Undergraduate student academic CV

Tags: cv

I am an undergraduate student and I am writing my CV which I am going to send to my professor for a position as a junior researcher. My questions are:

- How should I present my education (including the bachelor that I am going to finish in a year) ?
- I am currently doing my thesis which I am going to finish in 6 months. How should I present it given that I haven't finished it yet ?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I usually see students present education and work in progress:

> **Bachelor of Science**, *expected December 2019*
>
> *University of State*
>
> Major: Physics
>
> - Senior Thesis: "Reflection of bivariate light distributions" (Expected completion July 2019).
> - Major GPA 3.78/4.00
>
> Minor: Greek History

Using the "expected" tag is usually an indicator that the work/degree is not yet completed, but is in progress. If the project lead has further questions he/she can ask you about your work in more detail. They likely are perfectly aware that you have not completed everything for the degree. People apply for jobs all the time under the premise of expected education/projects.

Answer (score 0):

As a post grad (BSc) not currently in an advanced degree program I can only say what my approach would be. Firstly id listen with all ears to Vladhagen, being personally experienced in the revirw of such documents.

But as for my humble opinion, id just be straight up. Describe succinctly/briefly the topic/title of the thesis, maybe include some of the thought processes that led to the substance of the paper, (the addition of an expected time of completion is not something id have thought of but is an excellent idea).

Depending on how descriptive/well understood the content of your degree is i might include a list of the relevant modules/classes that show your specialist studies. For example i did a Natural Sciences degree (a vague descriptor im sure you'd agree), however it was a molecular/cellular bio and classical chem double major, so after year one there was no geology, no whole life bio, no evolution, no physics (except that involved in physical chemistry etc) so it was necessary to specify the detail of what i actually had been educated in.

Hope that gives you something to think about.